# Changing button value based on checkboxes selected individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, checkbox

There are 2 things that the linked function doesn't account for that I was hoping to figure out:

1. If you select checkboxes individually, the button doesn't change its displayed value to "Deselect All".
2. If you select a single checkbox and then deselect the same checkbox, the "Select All" button is set to uncheck first - even if there is nothing checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/point71echo/pxxnhb35/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="first">
    <input type="button" id="checkAll" value="Select All " data-type="uncheck">  

        <div class="button">    
            <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="Item 1" class="first">
            <label for="Item 1" class="label1">Item 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="Item 2" class="first">
            <label for="Item 2" class="label1">Item 2</label><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="Item 3" class="first">
            <label for="Item 3" class="label1">Item 3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option1" id="Item 4" class="first">
            <label for="Item 4" class="label1">Item 4</label><br><br>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // below code is used to remove all check property if,
    // user select/unselect options with class first options.    
    $(".first").click(function(){
        $("#checkAll").attr("data-type","uncheck"); 
                $(this).val('Select All');
    });

    $("#checkAll").attr("data-type","check");
    $("#checkAll").click(function(){
        if($("#checkAll").attr("data-type")==="check")
          {
            $(".first").prop("checked",true); 
            $("#checkAll").attr("data-type","uncheck");
                $(this).val('Deselect All')
          }
        else
          {
            $(".first").prop("checked",false);
            $("#checkAll").attr("data-type","check");
                $(this).val('Select All');
          }
    }) 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you only tell what does not work and what works incorrectly it's hard to figure out what the desired behaviour should be. Try code below:

```
$(".first").click(function(){
    if ($(".first:checked").length > 0) {
        $("#checkAll").("data-type","uncheck").('Deselect All');
    } else {
        $("#checkAll").("data-type","check").('Select All');
    }
});
```

Now when you check one or more checkboxes the type and text will change to 'Deselect all'
When there are no checked boxes than the button says 'Select All'

Comment: I'm trying to retain all of the functionality already set up, while having any individual checkbox that is checked cause the button to read "Deselect All". I meant to remove the extra code. Here's an updated fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/point71echo/pxxnhb35/3/

Comment: have a look at changed answer

Comment: My previous statements were to imply that all functionality currently available in my original code are desired. I am only hoping to tweak this code so that when one or more checkboxes are selected, the button changes its text to read "Deselect All". I am very new to jQuery, so I have a limited vocabulary and I apologize if I have been confusing. I wasn't able to get your code to work. Can you save a functioning version of it to a Fiddle so that I can see all of the code together in case I am missing something. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In reality there are few issues with your code in terms of flexibility and maintainability.

The reasons being:

1. You're checking the data-type attribute not the checkbox value.
2. You run the function on clicking the button. Thus, if a checkbox is clicked thereafter the event is not registered.

---

**This is what I would do:**

```
$('#checkAll').click(function (event) { //on click 
    if ($("#checkAll").attr("data-type") === "unchecked") { // check select status
        $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"
            $("#checkAll").val('Deselect All');
            $("#checkAll").attr("data-type", "checked");
        });
    } else {...
```

I've set up a fiddle for you, which is far from perfect but it goes towards your goals.

http://jsfiddle.net/carlodurso/uLbwunwh/

*Happy tweaking.*